# How to install old AMD Catalyst 12.4 drivers on Ubuntu 12.10?

Tags: ati, fglrx, 12.10, downgrade, catalyst

I have an ATi Radeon HD 3650 AGP, which does not support 12.8 and 12.9 drivers. The latest supported version is 12.4, but Catalyst 12.4 does not support Ubuntu 12.10. How can I downgrade to 12.4 or 12.6 Catalyst drivers in Ubuntu 12.10?

Comment: Please edit your question - HD 3650 IS supported by Catalyst 12.6. I'm using it on Ubuntu 12.04 LTS. You can verify this by going to the official AMD download page http://support.amd.com/us/gpudownload/Pages/index.aspx After you select HD 3650 you will be offered driver version 12.6 download. You probably saw the information about 12.4 being the last one that supports HD 3650 on some outdated Wiki.

Comment: @Bucic Edited, but official Catalyst 12.6 didn't work for me. Maybe not working with AGP card or installation went wrong?

Comment: Weird. I have the 3650 in my Lenovo Thinkpad T500.

Comment: @nastys:  The answer is here http://askubuntu.com/a/129200/53498

Answer (score 7):

I haven't tried it yet but I found [this PPA.](https://launchpad.net/~makson96/+archive/fglrx)

The latest fglrx that supports pre-HD5000 GPUs, is [Catalyst 12.6 Legacy.](http://support.amd.com/us/kbarticles/Pages/catalyst126legacyproducts.aspx)

But it doesn't support Ubuntu 12.10 from what I have heard. I am also concerned about this as I want to update to Quantal but fgrlx is a must have for me. I still don't have Quantal so I could not test it. Test it at your own risk.

Comment: I installed the drivers from the PPA but no graphics acceleration

Comment: Do I have to downgrade Xorg and other packages?

Comment: @nastys No one really knows. I'd suggest adding this question to your favorites http://askubuntu.com/questions/124292/what-is-the-correct-way-to-install-ati-catalyst-video-drivers so you get a notification when it's updated.

Comment: I tried installing fglrx-legacy, but there's an "AMD Unsupported hardware" watermark, because it doesn't work.

Comment: Tomasz Makarewicz's PPA tested on Lenovo Thinkpad T500 with AMD Radeon HD3650. The driver installed fine. Apparently it required downgrading Xorg but it's all done automatically. I haven't conducted any performance tests.

Comment: it worked for me, on Ubuntu 12.10! Sony Vaio VGN-FW31E with Mobility Radeon HD 3400 Series

Comment: struggling whether it's worth to downgrade Xorg to install legacy driver and probably not even then get decent acceleration, and that just for using unity ... tempted to look for a replacement gpu or replacement os instead.

Comment: also worked for me on Sony VAIO VGN-FW490 with Mobility Radeon HD4650

Answer (score 0):

[this ppa](https://launchpad.net/~makson96/+archive/fglrx) works for me 
I have Mobility Radeon HD 3650